# How do pilots board the B-1B Lancer?

Tags: aircraft-design, doors, rockwell-b-1-lancer

I've noticed that there isn't any type of hatch/plug door near the canopy of the B-1B Lancer. How do pilots enter and exit the aircraft?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The crew of [Rockwell B-1 Lancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_B-1_Lancer) (4 in total) enter or exit the cockpit from the underside, using a ladder. It can be seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/aYqKZsM0kU0?t=1m20s).

This picture shows the ladder (the one on the right):

[image: Cockpit enterance]
<sup>[*Image Source*](http://www.afcent.af.mil/Units/455thAirExpeditionaryWing/Photos/tabid/238/igphoto/2000186381/Default.aspx)</sup>

On the top of the ladder, there is a door, which looks like this:

[image: entry door]
<sup>[*Image Source*](http://www.aircraftresourcecenter.com/awa01/001-100/awa001-B-1/00.shtm)</sup>

Comment: That's not a ladder -- it's a bookshelf!

Answer (score 19):

This picture shows a ladder behind the front landing gear.

[image: Ladder]
<sup>[Image Source](http://cdn-www.airliners.net/aviation-photos/photos/8/1/6/1561618.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Why is it situated behind the landing gear?

Comment: @MadhavSudarshan not enough room in front (the gear retracts forwards) and symmetry

Comment: @MadhavSudarshan If there are crew riding on the jump seats, they do not have ejection seats and the bail out is manual through this hatch.  If the hatch was in front of the nose wheel, this would be a problem if they had to bail out when the gear is down.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want to be in one of those jump seats if the pilots thought ejecting was a good idea. They're risky enough in multi-crew aircraft even when everyone has one, especially in side-by-side configuration (one reason the F-111 used cabin ejection instead of rocket seats; this design was also considered for the B-1).

Comment: The B-1A did have an escape capsule.  It was changed to ejection seats for the B-1B.  http://www.check-six.com/Crash_Sites/B-1_crash_site.htm