# How does a pilot board a B-2 Spirit?

Tags: doors, b-2

I haven't noticed any sort of plug door, so how do pilots board the B-2?

Answer (score 12):

There is a hatch and a ladder in the *bottom* of the front fuselage, through which the pilots enter the bomber, as seen [here](http://media.airspacemag.com/images/Stealth-Bomber-Elite-631.jpg):

[image: Pilot hatch seen slightly to the left of the cockpit.]

Comment: Why have such a design? In the case of a belly landing, wouldn't the pilot be trapped inside?

Comment: @MadhavSudarshan I would imagine it has something to do with the process of applying various stealth technologies and materials on the top of the fuselage, which something like a movable canopy, for example, could have compromised. Also, considering how the United States have superiority when it comes to advanced stealth technologies, I assume that an emergency landing on hostile territory would necessitate a self-destruction of the bomber. On friendly territory the plane could just be taken apart to get the pilots out; the bomber would be ruined from a stealth flight perspective anyhow.

Comment: @MadhavSudarshan there are most probably zero-zero ejection seats and the upper escape panels above the cockpit might be able to jettison on their own.

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot - there are indeed ejection seats, as the only loss of a B-2 did not involve the pilots - they ejected safely. In most ejection seat aircraft, ejection is preferable to a belly landing

Comment: There are still ways to escape if the main exit is blocked. A B-1 has a [similar arrangement](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14669/1696), and the pilots got out after a [belly landing](http://www.aero-news.net/aNNTicker.cfm?do=main.textpost&id=2fd82305-65bd-4b85-809f-7faf1b07988e).